# Need help with cumulative distribution function problem.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

A commercial water distributor supplies an office with gallons of water once
a week. Suppose that the weekly supplies in tens of gallons is a random
variable with pdf

$$f(x)= \begin{cases} 
      5(1-x)^4 & 0\lt x\lt 1 \\
      0 & otherwise
   \end{cases}
$$

Approximately, how many gallons should be delivered in one week so that
the probability of the supply is 0.1?  Answer key says 4 gallons.

My attempt:  I first find $F(t)$  $$\int_0^t 5(1-x)^4dx=-(1-x)^5|_0^t=1-(1-t)^5$$ therefore 
$$F(x)= \begin{cases}
        1-(1-x)^5 & 0\lt x \lt 1 \\
        0 & otherwise
        \end{cases}
$$ now I thought I needed to solve $$0.1=P(0 \lt X \lt x)=F(x)-F(0)=1-(1-x)^5$$

$$1+(-0.9)^{\frac{1}{5}}=x \implies x \approx1.979.$$  If someone could explain what is I am supposed to be solving or what I have done wrong that would be very helpful.

Comment: The actual question is less than clear but I suspect that you may be supposed to be calculating $10 \times \left(1-(1-0.9)^{1/5} \right) \approx 3.7$ gallons.  You certainly have some signs wrong

Comment: The wording is not very clear, but I expect that the weekly **demand** is given by your formula. We want to have probability $0.1$ of **running out**. So we want the $x$ such that $1-(1-x)^5=0.9$, as in Henry's comment. Small office!

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks for the help I understand now.

Comment: @user101388: You are welcome.

Comment: $X \sim Beta(1, 5)$ and in R `qbeta(.9, 1, 5)` returns 0.3690427. Multiplied by 10, I guess that's close to 4 gallons. If the beta distribution is not in your text, see Wikipedia. In R, `qbeta` is the inverse CDF.